# How do I add an arbitrary link to the WordPress Admin Menu?

Tags: wordpress, menu, admin

I am looking to add an arbitrary link to the WordPress Admin Menu.

Example:

```
| Dashboard |

|   Posts   |

|   Media   |

|  Custom Arbitrary Link  |
```

The functionality of this acts just like a normal button but when you press it it redirects you to any URL given such as Google.

Can anyone help me by providing instructions and or source code? I know there is a lot of documentation on how to add menus but I haven't been able to find much about just linking to specific websites.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use in your plugin/template a function [add_object_page](https://codex.wordpress.org/add_object_page)

```
add_object_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url );
```

create new function that will be use to make redirect

```
function redirect_to() {
   header('Location: http://www.example.tld/');
   exit();
}
```

and use that function name as 5th ($function) argument when you call add_object_page:

```
 add_object_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, redirect_to, $icon_url );
```

all parameters except $icon_url are required, so read [codex documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/add_object_page)